# XBOX One Permission over TCP Socket

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, xbox

I have developed a unity game which listens to a TCP port. I have used `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` class to achieve this.

I have ported the game for UWP (using IL2CPP scripting backend). I also have checked **internetClientServer** and **privateNetworkClientServer** capabilities in the *Visual Studio*.

After creating the package and installing the package using *XBOX Remote Access*, it will work successfully. But after restarting the console the game crashes when a client wants to connect.

Exception: **The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.**

Appreciate any help

Comment: Did you mean it can work after installing successfully, only restart the console it will crash? What's the client? Did the client also in the same XBOX? What's the platform version?

Comment: Yes, it will work after install. But after turning off the console and turning it on again, it will not work. Currently, my clients are an android phone app and a WPF application which as I said they communicate through TCP/IP. XBOX OS Version is 10.0.16299.3036.